# How to remove navigation bar in Streamlit on login page?

Tags: authentication, navbar, streamlit, authenticator

Streamlit picks up everything located in the *pages* folder and places it in the navigation bar.

Is there a way to completely remove the navigation bar on selected pages?
I'm using streamlit_authenticator and would like to remove (not just hide) the nav bar only on the login page, where it doesn't make sense anyway.

The workaround

st.markdown(" ul {display: none;} ", unsafe_allow_html=True)

still leaves and (empty) sidebar with the cancellation x.